# finding a regular length

Tags: automata

i am trying to find a regular language that: her minimum pumping length = number states of minimum Nondeterministic automata that receive the language  = number of equivalence classes. (not 1)

any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

HINT: You can do it with a one-character alphabet $\Sigma=\{a\}$ and an automaton having two states. This gives you a choice of two regular languages that will work.